# wpf windows media player's COM addin, not working after windows update in win8

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have developed a wpf application which includes a windows media player's COM addin and it worked perfectly on windows, but after a few windows update my application making nonsense enexpected things, it is not working properly.

In short, i tested different workarounds on it but no luck, some of are:

Tried different laptop to run application with Windows 7 installed. Status,working.

Then tried one more laptop with windows 8. status, worked on that too.

Finally i reinstalled my application. Status, worked for 2-3 days properly but then same problem is happening.

Now the situation is this, i don't know the root cause of problem.
If i guess, it is all about the windows packages installed by windows update.

Or if i am wrong please correct me.

I need a solution. Please help. 
Somebody facing same problem or have an idea about what causing it.

Edit: as suggested i will try to make you understand my problem, but this is the main problem that their is no error message,nothing happens that is what is happening.
I am passing path for video file to the player then in left corner above control, text appears, eg. Opening Sample.m2p. 
After this, another text appears saying ready and nothing happens,  tried pressing play button several times but no luck.

Comment: providing information like, what exceptions you're getting and how its behaving would help.  Usually showing some code on a software Q&A site is helpful too.